# laravel Excel Import set header on column

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I have an import function from `laravel excel`, it worked but now I want to add a header on it and its not working, There's only 1 column in my excel sheet and the header is called `Unit Type`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\UnitType;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class UnitTypesImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow
{
    protected $user_id;
    protected $proj_id;

    public function __construct($user_id, $proj_id)
    {
        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->proj_id = $proj_id;
    }

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {   
            $unit_types_count = UnitType::where('name', $row[0])->where('project_id', $this->proj_id)->count();
            if ($unit_types_count == 0){
                UnitType::create([
                    'name'       => $row['unit_type'],
                    'created_by' => $this->user_id,
                    'project_id' => $this->proj_id,
                ]);
            } 
        } 
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

when I try using the method `WithHeadingRow` it now gives me an **error** as:

> Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Continuing with @thmspl's answer,

Use `$row['unit_type']` in the line

`$unit_types_count = UnitType::where('name', $row[0])->where('project_id', $this->proj_id)->count();`

instead of `$row[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

`headingRow` method is only required when your Heading is at a row other than 1st Row. In your case since the Heading is first row you can remove the following method.

```
public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Docs https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html you don't have to add the `headingRow()` function if your header is on the first line.

So try to remove the `headingRow()` function and execute it again.